# after putting dropdown, containing anchor tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

After putting *bootstrap* drop-down inside, containing `<a></a>`is not working, even though drop down is working fine, it has also messed up with styling after incorporating, thanks in advance

```
<a href="{% url 'jobmanage:job-det' val.id %}" class="card-link"> <-- this link is not working 
    <div class="card jobs_cards" >
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="btn btn-scondary" dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
           
         
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h5 class="card-title">
          {{val.title}}
        </h5>

        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{val.cmpny_name.name}}</h6>

        <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{val.salary_start}} - {{val.salary_end}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{val.job_description}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: `<a>` is not permitted content in [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties), browsers will pull out the inner anchors and place them after the parent `a`, that brakes the styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good method(not possible) to have your styles (card, heading...) inside `<a>` tag .

Instead you can use **JS** function to open the link on click of card :

```
<div class="card jobs_cards" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>



function myFunction() {
window.open("wwww.urlGoesHere.com", "_top");
}
```

[Here is some more content about `window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)